# What is this thumbnail icon on mobile chrome and how to use it in my website

Tags: css, html

I don't know what this icon is called and how to use it for my website. Can someone help me out.

[image: Thumbnail icon on mobile chrome.]

Comment: Try google reverse image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'd be one of the favicons you need to set on your page. If you use an automatic tool like https://realfavicongenerator.net you will be able to easily cover all the required different files using a single image.

> The icon that is used to install to the homescreen is determined by using the largest icon found in one of the following  tags:

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="nice-highres.png"> (recommended)
<link rel="icon" sizes="128x128" href="niceicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="niceicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="128x128" href="niceicon.png">
```

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen#icon

> Chrome uses the same icon as the favicon, bookmark icon and “Add to home screen” icon. It picks the widest PNG icon it can find which is no larger than 192×192.

Source: https://realfavicongenerator.net/blog/android-chrome-and-its-favicon/

Answer (score 0):

It's called favicon. Somewhere you should have a code like this:

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" />
```

Follow the href to the location. You can find it in your header somewhere.